# How to find address of an array element defined as macro in C in linux

Tags: c, arrays, linux, macros

```
#define Te0 (u32)((u64*)((u8*)Te+0))
#define Te1 (u32)((u64*)((u8*)Te+3))
#define Te2 (u32)((u64*)((u8*)Te+2))
#define Te3 (u32)((u64*)((u8*)Te+1))



static const u64 Te[256] = {
    U64(0xa56363c6a56363c6), U64(0x847c7cf8847c7cf8),
    .....}
```

In have this sample C code, where array Te0,Te1,Te2 and Te3 is defined as macro whereas Te is defined as static array initialized with 256 unsigned long long value.

I understand for Te array, valid index is 0-255 and I can print address of i^th  element of Te array as &Te[i]

When I try to print address as &Te0[0], it throws error as

```
error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

I have following questions regarding macro style defined array .

1. What is the valid index for Te0 array? Te1 array?
2. What is starting & end address of Te0 array ? Te1 array?
3. How to calculate and print address of i^th  element of Te0 array as &Te0[i] throws error?
4. What is the meaning of (Td+0), (Td+1), (Td+3) in macro definition of array ?

I am using gcc in linux.

Thank you

**EDIT-1:** I agree,macro is expanded at compile time, but have doubt how the following expression evaluated correctly, when s0 and s1 is known at run time (different value of s0 and s1 at different run) and macro expansion done at compile time?

```
t[0] =  Td0[(s0      ) & 0xff] ^
        Td1[(s3 >>  8) & 0xff]
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `(u32)((u64*)((u8*)Te+0))` is *not* an [l-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-value) (but a cast probably losing information) so you can't take its address (likewise you cannot take the address of an unary minus)

You need some intermediate step like

```
  #define TTe0 (*((u8*)Te+0))
```

and then you can write `&TTe0`

If you have many macro definitions similar to your `#define Te0` you could write some script (perhaps using `sed` or `awk`) to generate a header containing such `#define TTe0` then include it appropriately.

Remember that C code (so header files) can be generated! You could then adjust your build procedure (e.g. edit some `Makefile`) for that purpose.

Read more about the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) in particular its [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). You can get (then study) the preprocessed form with `gcc -C -E`

(regarding your other questions, please read a good C programming book, then read the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard i.e. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf); the fact that an expression came from some macro expansion is irrelevant once the preprocessing did happen, and the compiler mostly sees the preprocessed form)

Your question has a misleading title: it is not a matter of taking the address thru a macro, but of taking the address of some cast, which is obviously meaningless.

You can take an address thru a macro. A typical example would be `&errno` since [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) is a macro (defined in *internal* header file `/usr/include/bits/errno.h` which gets included thru `<errno.h>` standard header).

Comment: I am wondering if address is not calculatable, then how compiler be able to point to any element by Te0 at run time ?

Comment: You need to read a good C programming book. A cast is some operation (like e.g. the unary minus is). You can't take the address of a negation (e.g. `&(-x)`), and likewise you can't take the address of a cast.

Comment: There is a linear relationship exist between base address of array and valid index when array is defined in normal way. i.e. address of Te[i]= base address + i*w where w is word size.

Comment: And if the type is required to be `u32*`, `(*(u32*)((u8*)Te+0))` would be better

Comment: Yes, but we don't know (and only guess) the meaning of `u32`